# Can you modify edge to open a .pdf in private browser?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to modify edge through the registry to open a .pdf in a private edge browser instead of normal mode? I understand the process of stopping it from opening in an edge browser by editing the settings and then the registry entry but changing its target to something like --inprivate, is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

1. Save the following script as a cmd file, for example *MSEdgeInprivatePDF.cmd*, in a new folder.

   ```
   @echo off

   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

   reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF > nul

   if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
       echo Error: Could not find registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF'
       goto :END
   )

   echo y | reg export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF MSEdgePDF.reg > nul

   if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
       echo Error: exporting registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF'
       goto :END
   )

   echo y | type MSEdgePDF.reg > MSEdgePDF.txt

   del MSEdgePDF.reg

   set newline=^



   set s=

   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (MSEdgePDF.txt) do (

       set n=%%i
       set n=!n:[=!
       if !n! neq %%i set s=!s!!newline!

       if !s!x equ x (
           set s=%%i
       ) else set s=!s!!newline!%%i
   )

   del MSEdgePDF.txt

   set s=!s:msedge.exe\"=msedge.exe\" --inprivate!
   set s=!s:MSEdgePDF=MSEdgeInprivatePDF!
   set s=!s:"MSEdge"="MSEdgeInprivate"!
   set s=!s:"Microsoft Edge"="Microsoft Edge Inprivate"!
   set s=!s!!newline!!newline![HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\OpenWithProgids]!newline!"MSEdgeInprivatePDF"=""

   echo !s! > MSEdgeInprivatePDF.reg

   echo Operation successful :^)

   :END
   pause
   ```
2. Double click on the cmd file to run it.

    If the output shows **Operation successful :)**, then close the command prompt window. If it shows any error post it in the comments below.
3. **Proceed only if previous step was successful.**

    Notice a registry file named **MSEdgeInprivatePDF.reg** is created in the folder.
4. Double click on the registry file to run it. (Select "Yes" wherever necessary)
5. Right click on any pdf file and open **Properties** window.
6. Click on the **change** option near *Opens with* section.
7. Look for the option **Microsoft Edge Inprivate** and select it.
8. Finally, click on **Apply** in the *Properties* window.

Now, double click on any pdf file and it would open in a InPrivate window.

Optional: You can delete the cmd and registry files after following the above steps.

Comment: @KJ thank you for pointing out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KJ It's weird that in my system msedge.exe is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application` even though it is a 64 bit system. After a quick google search I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/878582/why-ms-edge-64-bit-browser-installed-in-program-fi).  Anyways I have made the changes taking your advice :) Tell me if anything else is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add flags in Edge target to open a pdf in Edge InPrivate window. You can right click Edge shortcut -> click **Properties**-> at the end of **Target**, add pdf url and `--inprivate` flags. After this, next time you double click the Edge shortcut, it will open the pdf in InPrivate window directly.

[image]

Comment: This only modifies a shortcut. The OP wants to configure it so that double-clicking on any PDF will open it in a private browser.